# Stop reloading the whole content on route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have a route like the following: `page/:id`, where it loads a different content for each `id`. However, every time I go to a different page, it reloads the entire content. I'd like to reload only the data coming from the API.

Navigation:

```
<ul>
 <li [routerLink]="['/page', 1]">Page 1</li>
 <li [routerLink]="['/page', 2]">Page 2</li>
 <li [routerLink]="['/page', 3]">Page 3</li>
</ul>
```

Template:
`<h1 *ngIf="data">{{data.name}}</h1>`

Component:

```
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any;
  error: any;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private service: DataService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    this.service.getData()
      .subscribe(
        res => this.data = res,
        error => this.error = error
      );
  }

}
```

If you go to this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QGqdw4roSYKIoTuyANSd?p=preview), you'll see the black rectangle blinks every time the route changes. Ideally, the black part would remain intact, only the data inside would change.

I also noticed this flickering behavior happens only if I'm using an HTTP call. If I'd have other things in that component, this wouldn't happen when changing routes.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**EDIT**: [Here's a Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZITXyhXAmWWk2hor13ea?p=preview) showing the expected behavior. However, I was using former `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`, which are deprecated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending @Rob's answer, I did manage to solve this issue using the `Resolve` guard. However, I was making a few mistakes in its implementation.

I've created a new `data-resolve` where I resolve the `HTTP` call before initializing the route:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataResolve implements Resolve {

  constructor(private service: DataService, private router: Router) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot):
    Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
      return this.service.getData().then(data => {
        if (data) {
          return data;
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/page/1']);
         return false;
       }
    });
  }
}
```

Then, I needed to add that service to my module's providers:

`providers: [DataService, DataResolve]`

And also tell the routing to solve that before loading the route:

`resolve: { pages: DataResolve }`

After that, I'll have an array I can use in my component to get the data:

```
this.route.data.forEach((data: {pages}) => {
  this.data = data.pages;
});
```

I've also updated my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8l2GwRzhcVKF4xUea55o?p=preview) with a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Your blinking occurs because when you navigate, `DataComponent` is destroyed and re-built, but it cannot be shown until new data arrives from the server because you block its display with `*ngIf="data"`.  [On this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ppP456DrcEGzTz8xaWIR?p=preview), I've added a 1 second delay to the server response to make the problem obvious. Note that only the `DataComponent` blinks. The rest of `PagesComponent` does not.

[On this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eBUNGXzC4ayIfNdee2e3?p=preview), there is no visible blinking because the data is hard-coded so there is no wait for the server's response.

To alleviate the blinking, don't use `*ngIf` since that removes the element from the dom entirely. [On this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A9QmfWQssqw6jYbOm3Xt?p=preview), no blinking occurs even while we wait for data to arrive from the server.

Basically, as long as you choose to hide the element until data arrives, whenever the component is re-initialized you will see blinking.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Actually, my issue remains. Let's say the data doesn't change (despite changing the route, the `name` property is the same). It should keep the same data (without blinking). I remember I had something like that while using RC.4 and `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` but, apparently, the behavior changed on RC.5. I'll try to post a Plunkr later.

Comment: Here's the Plunker with the behavior I expect: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZITXyhXAmWWk2hor13ea?p=preview - I'm actually using RC.5 but `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` instead of `RouterModule`. I wonder if it's possible to have the same behavior as `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` is deprecated now.

Comment: @drbishop your original code is subject to an Angular bug. The router is supposed to re-use the same instance of a component when navigating to the same component (even if parameters change).  However, as of `Angular rc 5`, this mechanism fails on lazy-loaded components, so your `PagesComponent` is being destroyed and recreated even if no data changes.  See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10987

Comment: thanks for the update. Apparently, they've fixed this for RC.6 :)

Answer (score 0):

You are already only reloading the content coming from the API. The black box is flickering because you are styling the `h1` and the `h1` is changing. If you want the box there for every page then move it up to the `AppComponent`s template.

```
<div class="box">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Then move the styles to the `.box` selector rather than the `h1`.

Another issue will be the height of the box will collapse and expand while the content is removed and refreshed. You can fix this by using a resolve guard on your routes.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard

Comment: I see. However, I wonder if there isn't another way. If I have a more complex structure, I'd still have the same issue: the black box would remain but other static information inside of it would still flicker. I also noticed this behavior happens only if I'm using an HTTP call. If I'd have other things in that component, it wouldn't flicker when changing routes.

Comment: It shouldn't flicker if you use the resolve guard because the route wont be loaded until the http request resolves from the server.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I've updated my Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8l2GwRzhcVKF4xUea55o?p=preview